# How to generically replace a string with another using a variable

Tags: php, string, variables, preg-replace, preg-match

**Problem:**

I am stuck in figuring out how to add a string in a variable to a number of different strings using PHP.

**Variable:**

```
$insert = 'icon-white';
```

**Strings are in a variable called $hyperlink:**

```
$hyperlink = '<i class="icon-home"></i>';
```

**Desired output:**

```
<i class="icon-home icon-white"></i>
```

Any recommendations are welcome, and thanks in advance.

Comment: It's actually an array but I use $hyperlink[0] to access the string, but for the sake of simplicity just go with that it is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly don't see the benefits of regex in this particular question, so I've chosen to disregard that aspect; the principal concern seems to be to insert the new string before the last `"` character, which can be achieved with the following:

```
$hyperlink = '<i class="icon-home"></i>';
$insert = ' icon-white'; // I've explicitly prefixed the new string with a space
$pos = strripos($hyperlink,'"',0);
echo substr_replace($hyperlink,$insert,$pos,0)
```

If you'd rather, then, for future use, here's a function that will insert a given string (`$new`) into another string (`$haystack`) before the last occurrence of a given character (`$needle`):

```
function insertBeforeLast($haystack,$needle,$new){
    if (!$haystack || !$needle || !$new){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return substr_replace($haystack,$new,strripos($haystack,$needle),0);
    }
}

    echo insertBeforeLast('abcdefg','e','12',' ');
```

The `0` before the closing parenthesis of `substr_replace()` in the function denotes the number of characters that the newly-inserted string will overwrite in the original string.

---

**Edited** to amend the above function to explicitly offer the over-writing as an option:

```
function insertBeforeLast($haystack,$needle,$new, $over){
    if (!$haystack || !$needle || !$new){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $over = $over || 0;
        return substr_replace($haystack,$new,strripos($haystack,$needle),$over);
    }
}

    echo insertBeforeLast('abcdefg','e','12',0);
```

References:

- [`strripos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php).
- [`substr_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php).

Comment: I HIGHLY appreciate this, it made more sense to me than the regexp, although that version works I understand what's going on in this solution. However, this is a great moment to start diving into the world of regexp.

Comment: You're very welcome; obviously I'd encourage you to consider having this as your 'accepted' answer, but I am, of course, terribly biased! Just a suggestion, though, but if you leave a comment on [sputnick's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10963911/82548) asking for an explanation, he'll probably provide one happily enough. Regex is, after all, not easy to learn.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to use `preg_replace()` php function to fit your needs :

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $oldvar = '<i class="icon-home"></i>';
php > $newvar = preg_replace('/(.*?".*?)"(.*)/', '\1 icon-white"\2 ', $oldvar);
php > echo $newvar;
<i class="icon-home icon-white"></i>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output be: <i class="icon-home icon-white"></i> ?

Comment: Your output is: <i class="icon-home" icon-white"></i> - there's an extra quote after the home word.

Answer (score 0):

When rendering the output, you could do;

```
<i class="icon-home <?= $insert ?>"></i>
```

if you don't want it to be conditional.

If you have a variable;

```
$i = '<i class="icon-home"></i>';
```

you can do;

```
$i = '<i class="icon-home ${insert}"></i>';
```

Comment: You need the `$` prefix for the variable (this *is* PHP after all), and I'd really suggest not using short-tags.

Comment: I have updated the question. The strings are in a variable and I'm looking for a preg solution where it looks for the last quote and insert " icon-white" before it.

Comment: Thanks for that catch David Thomas

Comment: David Thomas, intrigued as to why you wouldn't use short-tags, I did some searching around.I assume you recommended it because it's not always turned on.Doing a little research,I found that they're not part of short-tags anymore.